# Why do I have to reset my Visual Studio 2010 solution properties?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have:

- Visual Studio 2010 Premium Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
- Resharper 6.1
- One other minor Extension I got off of Extension Manager

The team is using Team Foundation Server 2010.

I haven't been able to figure exactly what things triggers this, but I constantly have to re-set my solution Startup Project configuration. I think it's whenever I restart my computer and after some "Get Latest" retrievals. Here's a screenshot of the source directory structure in **Source Control Explorer** (not Solution Explorer):

[image]

Any ideas why I would have to re-set those properties sometimes?

Comment: I guess you are doing a fresh checkout (into a clean folder). If so, the behavior is expected (well normal, at least).

Comment: Is your .vssscc file checked into source control?

Comment: @leppie: I do not do checkouts to a clean folder. I just click right click on the branch folder in the Source Control Explorer and click Get Latest (recursive). I use the same local folder everyday

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Yes, the screenshot shows that the *.vssscc file is in the repository. Shouldn't it be?

Comment: Actually, it's okay for the .vssscc file to be in source control

Comment: @gabe: That might be the reason :) As John said. I recall something along those lines.

Comment: @leppie: with TFS, the .vssscc is meant to be in source control. With SourceSafe, it was something to not check in.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Interesting. I have had TFS b*tching at me about that file a while back (especially when branching).

Comment: @leppie: idk what your issue was ("write a separate question", but you know that already), but I recall the VSS guidance, but now, TFS wants you to check the file in. It also get's checked out for no good reason, but that's a different story.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I did check it in when asked, but it seemed to forgotten about it when I made a branch. I'll make another branch at work tomorrow to see if the same happens.

Answer (score 2):

This setting 'lives' in the *.suo file. It is certainly [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298/should-i-add-the-visual-studio-suo-and-user-files-to-source-control) to insert this file into Source Control.
 In the picture you 're providing, there doesn't seem to exist one - but keep in mind that's a hidden file: so it makes sense to check if you actually have one checked in along with your other sources.
If yes, it absolutely makes sense that this gets changed with every GetLatest & you should probably remove it from your repository.
If not, having this issue only makes sense when you map your source every time in a clean folder like @leppie says.
Check also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876059/visual-studio-where-does-it-store-set-as-startup-project) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694730/why-is-set-as-startup-option-stored-in-the-sou-file-and-not-the-sln-file) for similar posts.

**EDIT**
OP commented below that his *.suo file was in fact not checked in - so the above passage is not really helpful. [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715594/visual-studio-not-remembering-open-documents-startup-project) SO post seems to have been the case instead. Following the instructions there, OP got his issue resolved.

Comment: The screenshot is the Source Control Explorer (I'll edit the question to make this more clear). The *.suo file is not in the repository. I don't map my source in a clean folder every time. I just click right click on the branch folder in the Source Control Explorer and click Get Latest (recursive). I use the same local folder everyday.

Comment: Hmm, then try deleting your *.suo and starting in a clean directory. According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715594/visual-studio-not-remembering-open-documents-startup-project, SUO can get corrupt and so VS will go for the defaults with each new try

Comment: The ***.suo*** should not be overwritten in a 'check out/get'. Edit: Argghhhhh, markdown making life difficult...

Comment: @pantelif: dang, I missed that question in my precursor search... I'll give it try it when I get a chance today

Comment: @pantelif: the solution in your second comment on this answer worked. wanna edit your answer to your second comment on this answer and i'll mark it answered?

Comment: @pantelif: to be clear, i changed my local directory and downloaded the entire project fresh.

Comment: ok, so this is weird but i haven't marked this as the answer because after changing my workspace location and re-downloading the entire solution from TFS, i'm still having the problem with my startup projects getting reset almost every time i restart VS. no one else on my team have this problem with the solution.