# How to save startup project preference in Visual Studio 2012 solution

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio solution which contains 2 projects (A and B).  Project B depends on Project A.  I would like to build both projects but only want project B to execute when I click the start button.

I can highlight Project B in the solution explorer and click on the Project menu to "Set as StartUp Project" and everything works fine on my end.  However when I check this into my git repo and share with someone else, Project A is always selected as the StartUp project on their solution.

My suspicion is that Visual Studio is saving this as a user setting instead of a project setting.

Is there any way to make the Project B persist as the StartUp project through a git checkin?

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate, but the "Startup Project" setting is [stored in the .suo file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876059/visual-studio-where-does-it-store-set-as-startup-project).  Checking that file in should propogate setting to others.  There's also this Visual Studio tip about [selecting start up projects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/07/29/did-you-know-how-to-select-the-startup-project-269.aspx) (in case you haven't seen it yet).

Comment: I don't have an .suo file.  Thanks for the first link as that question linked me to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1808352/2428480) where I found a solution to my answer!  Since I don't have a .suo file, Visual Studio chooses the first project that is loaded as the default startup project.  I had to edit my .sln file with a text editor and put Project B before Project A and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/756153/The-Solution-User-Options-Suo-File-in-Visual-Studi

maybe it's too late to say anything here, but I'm writing.

According to the page above, start-up project is saved in *.suo as it is a setting not for each project that is in the solution but for solution itself.

Comment: The referred article has been deleted.