# How do I make the Startup Project stick in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I understand from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876059/visual-studio-where-does-it-store-set-as-startup-project) that the Startup project is set in your .suo file.

And I understand from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298/should-i-add-the-visual-studio-suo-and-user-files-to-source-control) that storing your .suo file in TFS's source control system is generally frowned upon.

In my solution, the Startup Project is the second project in my solution. When I pull down a fresh copy of the solution from TFS, VS seems to default to the first project in the solution as the Startup Project. Is there another way to make my preferred Startup Project stick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694730/why-is-set-as-startup-option-stored-in-the-suo-file-and-not-the-sln-file) suggests, do the following:

Here is the trick: Close your Visual Studio and open the .sln file in your favorite text editor. Starting in line 4 you see all your projects encapsulated in Project - EndProject lines. If you don't have a .suo file in your solution directory, Visual Studio picks the first one as the default startup project. So just cut and paste your default startup one to the top position, delete your .suo file and open your solution in Visual Studio. Ta daa!