# How to save default startup project in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

What information does visual studio look at when determining the start-up project?

I have a C++ visual studio solution with 2 projects. My source control is messed up so I have to copy my solution folder from the repository to my local disk. When I do this and I run my application, the wrong project is set as the start-up project. In the repository I check in the .sln and .vcproj file as well as the cpp/h files, but not the .suo or .user files.

Comment: You do know that you can easily change the start up project from within the IDE?

Comment: I've found that in my case, if there is not suo file when a solution is opened, then the first project listen in the sln file is the startup project until the suo file is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Studio: Where does it store "Set as startup project"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876059/visual-studio-where-does-it-store-set-as-startup-project?_sm_au_=iVVF36vVjDQ0SQDQ)

The startup project is stored in the .suo. As mentioned in that SO post, you should not check these in, because they are not portable across machines/directories.