# Where are the settings for multiple startup projects on a solution stored?

Tags: visual-studio

I've got a Visual Studio solution containing a couple of console app projects, and used the solution property pages to launch both of them when debugging. For some reason, this setting isn't saved in source control so when I check out the solution on a different computer it has to be set up over again.

Where is this info stored and how can I add it to version control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it is in the Visual Studio User Solution User Options file *.suo. This file is hidden by default. Most source control providers ignore this file by default because it stores location specific paths.

Comment: What else is stored in *.suo? Why isn't it normally added to version control?

Comment: Because (1) it is specific to you, and (2) it changes all the time.

Comment: Check my update, here is another SO post on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694730/why-is-set-as-startup-option-stored-in-the-sou-file-and-not-the-sln-file

Comment: I have to admit, that it does seem like startup projects would be in the solution file...

Comment: Ah hmm..maybe I will just make one project launch the other and vice versa :) its mostly a demo anyway

Comment: I could see both angles, but working in large teams I understand where this would be problematic.

Answer (score 7):

You can install the [SwitchStartupProject](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4e1be8c-b2dd-4dec-b273-dd88f8818571) extension. This will create a file called `YourSolution.startup.suo` containing the startup projects, which you can check into source control.

See also their [wiki](https://bitbucket.org/thirteen/switchstartupproject/wiki/Home) for configuration instructions and other info.

Comment: thanks for posting, this is exactly what I was searching for

Comment: This extension is not installable on VS 2019 :(

Comment: Seems to work great with Visual Studio Professional 2022. A "professional" IDE should have this features itself, but who cares about his users... I often have to switch between debugging client & server and client only (with external server). I hardly understand how I could live without this extension until today. I probably went soft. :D