# Which file stores the Default project selection

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Where is the information about what is the default project set in a Silverlight/.NET application. Every time I check out code from svn, I have to manually set the default project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is stored in the .suo file that sits alongside the solution file.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694730/why-is-set-as-startup-option-stored-in-the-sou-file-and-not-the-sln-file) for more info.

Comment: My team usually excludes the suo file from SVN, and if one occasionally gets in there, we just delete it.