# startup projects and windows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a one solution with 3 projects, three windowsforms.
 I would like to have my main/startup project for form1 and which has 2 buttons. These should start form2/project2 and form3/project3.  But how can I do this ??

Comment: Marco and CodeCaster gave already the correct answer, but maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694730/why-is-set-as-startup-option-stored-in-the-sou-file-and-not-the-sln-file/1808352#1808352) is also valueable for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set references to other projects and then try something like this:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Show();

Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
frm3.Show();
```

or

```
YourClass2 cls2 = new YourClass2();
// Do what you need with it
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to Project2 and Project3 to Project1, then you can use the public classes from those projects.

```
private void Form1Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newForm = new Project2.Form2();
    newForm.Show(); // or ShowDialog to block
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to show these project.forms in a tabcontrol in the mainproject by any chance ?

Comment: @Nick_BE: don't use forms for that, but convert them to UserControls so you can include them everywhere!

Comment: Parhaps, if you set [`TopLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel.aspx) to `false`. But why would you do that? Creating a user control would indeed be the better option. If you need it somewhere 'standalone', you simply put it on a form.