# Only have iOs as debug options in Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, xamarin

I've just started with Xamarin Studio and since today Xamarin Forms.

When I tried Xamarin.Android I had my real device as option at the debug menu, and also emulators from Xamarin Android Player.

But now I wanted to try Forms for an Android and iOS project, but only get lots of iPhone options at debug menu.

My questions; how do I get Android devices and/or emulator options as well?

Update: Just for the record; http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging_with_xamarin/ only state: "To start debugging, select the target device or similar/emulator in your IDE:" and then a picture of the debug menu (or what it may be called)

Comment: Have you selected the Android project as start-up project?

Comment: hmmm... guess not since iOS project is in bold and looking closer I found the 'Set as Startup project' under the droid settings menu. And now it works! 1000 thanks!

Comment: More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302205/xamarin-forms-project-set-startup-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click YourAppName.Droid and you'll see "Set as Startup Project" :)