# Get the information related to start up project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a .net solution including 10 projects .
I have set one project as a Start up project.
I want to know where is the information related to setting start up project will be found.

Like if i added any file in any project then related information stored in the .cproj file of that project. in the same way where is the information related to setting start up project will be saved.

Comment: Which IDE are we taking about, Visual Studio, Xamarin, ...?

Comment: I am nearly certain that this info is proprietary to Visual Studio, and may change without a warning when a new version comes out.

Comment: Probably in the `.sln` file ?

Comment: visual studio vs 2013

Comment: I did not found any related changes in sln file of solution

Comment: [.suo file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/694730/815938)

Answer (score 1):

Startup information is related to each user. It's stored in `.suo` file. If such file doesn't exists. Visual Studio picks first project for startup.

Comment: I am unable to edit that file..Can i see the related information after editing?

Comment: I want to commit that .suo file on GIT Lab so that my other team member need not to set the start up project manually..But i am unable to edit the .suo file.and Although GUT Diff did not find any differences in .suo file after changing start up project..