# VS Crashing after 'Set As StartUp Project'

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I have a solution in VS 2012,
I try to change the startup project to **specific** project but the vs crashing immediately (with the other projects - no problem)
with the familiar message "Visual Studion Stop Working.."

I try also to define the startup project manualy in the .suo file
(See details in [Why is "Set as Startup" option stored in the suo file and not the sln file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694730/why-is-set-as-startup-option-stored-in-the-suo-file-and-not-the-sln-file))
But when i reopen the VS, it crashes during the assemblies loading.

Any idea what can be the cause?

**Edit:**

Additional Details:

Its solution contains also WCF project, run in front of local IIS, This project run perfectly, with the same code, in other team computers.
As result of the facts, It seems an environment problem, IIS setting, Permissions and etc.

Note that i already reset VS setting, and also repair the installation and the problem not resolved.

Maybe someone knows what the logical action of  'Set as startup project', what the VS perform during the action except for the start point definition? i think that the root of the problem hides there...

Comment: Please add more details to the question, like type of project, error details, screenshot if possible or any other details that could help in answering the Q.

Comment: @yogi:Thank for the attention, Its WinForms solution, including many project, One of theme is WCF project, contains .SVC services, Note that this project shared in team by TFS and it works perfect in all the computers exept for one problematic, Occording to this, it should be installition or personal setting.

Comment: See if the Windows firewall is blocking the VS or any port utilized in project's services. To avoid it, create a new entry in firewall giving access to all ports to VS.

Comment: Close VS. Delete your solution's *.suo file. Open VS. Set again. Did you open VS by administrator? Also try to disable Visual Studio extensions

Comment: @DavidBS: Thank you for the attention, It seems to me that is the direction, Becouse its the single soltion that doeswnt work and the single WCF project in our team, But i try all you wrote: I restart the firewall (that was disabled), i dont see any blocking on the port but howeverand i add new entry in firewall giving access to all ports to VS, I redefine the services in the local IIS and alternatively try using the IIS express but although all the problem not resolved yet, Any addition idea?

Comment: @MegaTron: Thanks, I try all (Including 'Repair' to VS 2012...), the problem not resolved, Any alternative?

Comment: @StackOverflow, without details about the crash it's impossible to try an effectiva solution. You need to add the details of the exception (LOGs and so forth).

Comment: @DavidBS: I will be glad to attach logs, but from there can i take them?

Comment: See here (and try to startup also in SAFE MODE before): http://blog.masterdevs.com/debugging-a-visual-studio-crash/  .

Comment: @DavidBS:  I try this but not accepted any error log, the VS crash also in SAFE MODE, In addition i try to empty the problematic project and it not help, I try create new and clean winForms solution and the problem happened, Also in VS 2010..., Its realy mystery, completely different from i thougt.. In every case, thank for your attention and for the important lesson regarding to VS logs!!

Comment: If the problem occurs everytime and with any VS, the problem may be related to the Windows and/or the .NET libraries; or even hardware (RAM). You're welcome...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, but on VS 2015. You should logoff from your MS account from VS, set your project as startup and then login back if you want ...

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to guess what the problem could be, but because it works on other team members' machine, it might have something to do with your Visual Studio state.

Try clearing or moving out all files from:

```
    C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio (if starting as admin)
    C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio (if not starting as admin)
```

You might need to restart your machine if the files are in use before you can delete/move them. These folders contain some VS settings, cached files and logs.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what AVS said, you can try deleting your Visual Studio .suo file.